# content-container looks small

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I'm creating a new angular app, I'm using [vmware-clarity](https://clarity.design/documentation/vertical-nav/basic-structure/project-pokemon) guide to do it, but my `navbar` and in general the `content-container` it's small and leaves a huge white space in the bottom

[image: content-container]

at the moment this is my code:

**Main app.component.html**

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**Horizontal navbar(this one is the above one)**

```html
<header class="header header-1">
    <div class="branding">
        <a href="..." class="nav-link">
            <span class="clr-icon resumeLogo"></span>
            <span class="title">Ricardo's Resume</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="header-nav">
        <a href="..." class="active nav-link">
            <span class="nav-text">
                About
            </span> 
        </a>
        <a href="..." class="nav-link">
            <span class="nav-text">
                Personal Information
            </span>
        </a>
        <a href="..." class="nav-link">
            <span class="nav-text">
                 Skils
            </span> 
        </a>
        <a href="..." class="nav-link">
            <span class="nav-text">
                 Work Experience
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="header-actions">
        <a href="..." class="nav-link nav-icon" aria-label="settings">
            <clr-icon shape="cog"></clr-icon>
        </a>
    </div>
</header>
```

**Vertical navbar**

```html
<div class="content-container" style="height: 100%;">
    <clr-vertical-nav [clrVerticalNavCollapsible]="true" 
        [(clrVerticalNavCollapsed)]="collapsed">
        <a clrVerticalNavLink routerLink="./normal" 
        routerLinkActive="active">
            <clr-icon clrVerticalNavIcon shape="user"></clr-icon>
                Normal
        </a>
        <a clrVerticalNavLink routerLink="./electric" 
        routerLinkActive="active">
            <clr-icon clrVerticalNavIcon shape="bolt"></clr-icon>
                Electric
        </a>
        <a clrVerticalNavLink routerLink="./poison" 
        routerLinkActive="active">
            <clr-icon clrVerticalNavIcon shape="sad-face"></clr-icon>
                Poison
        </a>
        <a clrVerticalNavLink routerLink="./grass" 
        routerLinkActive="active">
            <clr-icon clrVerticalNavIcon shape="bug"></clr-icon>
                Grass
        </a>
        <a clrVerticalNavLink routerLink="./fighting" 
        routerLinkActive="active">
            <clr-icon clrVerticalNavIcon shape="shield"></clr-icon>
                Fighting
        </a>
        <a clrVerticalNavLink routerLink="./credit" 
        routerLinkActive="active">
            <clr-icon clrVerticalNavIcon shape="certificate"></clr-icon>
                Credit
        </a>
    </clr-vertical-nav>
    <div class="content-area">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to be missing `main-container` and `header` - https://clarity.design/documentation/vertical-nav/basic-structure/project-pokemon#examples

Comment: @WandMaker I edited the question, I had them but in the `app.component`, and also I have another `navbar` (a horizontal one) in another component, there's where I have the `header`

Comment: I used your app.component.html and app-navbar in [stackblitz clarity](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v2) - I don't see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to the fact that Clarity uses an unusually large :root font-size of 24px.

So, if your :root font-size is smaller (as it should and probably is) it will show as way too small.

Solution: if you're OK with it, set your :root font-size, that you may find or declare on your global (s)css file, to 24px, like this:

```
:root { font-size: 24px }
```